# What are the basic files (dirs and regular file) in Ansible-Galaxy roles?

Tags: apache-httpd, php, ansible, syntax, stability

I have an Ansible playbook for establishing LAMP environments on remote machines.

Part of this playbook deals with installing Composer:

```
- name: Install Composer
  get_url:
    url: https://getcomposer.org/installer
    dest: /tmp/composer-setup.php
  command: php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

### My consideration

Instead these 5-lines structure I was thinking of using this `ansible-galaxy` command inside the playbook:

```
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.composer
```

[`geerlingguy.composer`](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-composer) is the most communally supported AG role with more than million users (so I assume that if there is a problem and Jeff isn't around at the moment - say, took vacation in Hawaii or something, there will be many community members to fix the problem and ensure stability.

Using this will also shorten my already quite-long playbook.

### My question

Why is Ansible-Galaxy role by our beloved Geerling (and some other similar roles) all include in GitHub the directories `defaults/`, `meta/` and `templates` and the `.travis.yml` file? in other words, Why a single playbook such as the one I wrote isn't enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta` contains meta-data used for the Galaxy registry. `.travis.yml` contains configuration for [Travis CI](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html#create-roles), which ensures that the project is continuously integrated. The other directories embody the typical structure of an Ansible role: `defaults` contains the default settings, `tasks` contains the playbooks, and `templates` contains the templates for generated files.

```
ansible-galaxy init
```

will create the default structure for you; see [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html#create-roles) for details. Currently, this is

```
README.md
.travis.yml
defaults/
    main.yml
files/
handlers/
    main.yml
meta/
    main.yml
templates/
tests/
    inventory
    test.yml
vars/
    main.yml
```

but you won’t see all this in all roles since few roles require every file and directory listed here.

If you look at the files in `tasks`, you’ll see that this particular role handles many more cases than your own playbook. That doesn’t mean that your own playbook isn’t “enough”; it explains why a structured approach is useful.